# how to save float number in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, precision

Before being saved in sqlite3, the float number is 37.80616719341899. Then I checked it in the database which is 37.806167193419. Here is my sql sentence:

```
create table if not exists RID3388 (latitude DOUBLE NOT NULL);
```

that's an example. I also tried datatype DECIMAL(38,20) but nothing helpful.
  I want to save the whole number in the database.
  Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: All floating-point numbers are stored as IEEE double-precision numbers. See http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: It is obvious that an approximate datatype such as `float` or `double` may save an approximation to the real value. (This is the reason these types are almost never used in a database.) But what was your issue with `decimal`?

Comment: according to the document, the datatype DECIMAL(a,b) means it can save b decimal places but it didn't work for my program. Is that right....

Comment: What document? The SQLite documentation says no such thing; DECIMAL(a,b) is just a normal floating-point number.

Comment: `DECIMAL` is frequently implemented on other databases, but not in SQLite (though it parses it as a floating-point number for compatibility). Please use the official SQLite documentation.